# convert python dict or csv file to a dataframe

Tags: python, numpy, dictionary, dataframe

I have a dictionary dump out as csv as below. How I convert it to dataframe
X,Y,SN as a header? I am thinking about writing a for loop and use split
but it doesnt seem very elegant nor efficient...

```
"49,42",001C0BA79A44
"49,43",001C0BA79A46
"49,40",001C0BA79A40
"49,41",001C0BA79A42
"67,22",001C0BA791E8
"65,31",001C0BA7991E
"67,23",001C0BA793BA
"64,25",001C0BA79416
"74,29",001C0BA79354
"65,33",001C0BA79922
"58,12",001C0BA78B2D
"65,32",001C0BA79920
"72,36",001C0BA79E08
"49,31",001C0BA79525
"65,51",001C0BA7A834
"62,46",001C0BA7A729
"49,30",001C0BA79523
"66,40",001C0BA79F45
"52,42",001C0BA7A07E
"58,17",001C0BA78F49
"52,40",001C0BA79A5E
"52,41",001C0BA79A60
"52,46",001C0BA7A0B8
"52,44",001C0BA7A082
"64,20",001C0BA791AD
"55,29",001C0BA7963E
"55,28",001C0BA7963C
"69,48",001C0BA7A689
"58,15",001C0BA78F45
"55,21",001C0BA79136
"55,20",001C0BA79134
"55,23",001C0BA7913A
"55,22",001C0BA79138
"55,25",001C0BA794A1
"55,24",001C0BA7949F
```

Comment: Use pandas.read_csv()

Answer (score 1):

Don't use a `for` loop, adding rows to an existing dataframe isn't very efficient.

```
def split(string):
     return string.split(',', 1)

df = pd.read_csv(file_path, header=None, names=['Cord', 'SN'])
df['X'], df['Y'] = zip(*df.Cord.map(split))
df = df[['X', 'Y', 'SN']]
```

See the documentation [here](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html).

Comment: Does the pandas reader handle the `"45,65",` format correctly?  It could cause problems with the numpy readers.

Comment: Missed that. I've edited the answer to deal with the fact that they're a single string.